# Publish an NPM module in two pattern styles

Tags: npm, webpack, umd

I have a package which is compiled to a UMD by Typescript and then converted to global vars by Webpack (We must use Typescript so a more flexible UMD pattern isn't an option). I want the applications that consume the package to be able to choose which they need. These will be deployed to a local NPM registry.

At the moment I have one package.json that lists all the required dependencies and build scripts. I don't mind publishing two different packages (probably to different scopes i.e. `@my-umd-packages\my-package` and `@my-globals-packages\mypackage` but I would want to keep a single package for all the dependencies and scripts as its all the same apart from the last step.

What's the neatest way to do this? Can a single package be published in two places with different `main` properties?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why would you have a version with globals and one with UMD? UMD falls back to a global variable, that's a crucial part of being **Universal** Module Definition.

Comment: @MichaelJungo - not a Typescript UMD. There is discussion about the issues and some workarounds here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8436

Comment: Ok, I've seen the discussion in [#2605](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2605) and it shouldn't be called UMD, but they ended up doing it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript doesn't fallback to a global variable, which should be part of an UMD module. There are possibilities for publishing multiple versions of your package. Frankly, it's rather special to have a separate module for globals, because most of the time UMD takes that part. The good news is that webpack does support this kind of module and will be able to produce it by setting the [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget).

```
output: {
  filename: 'mylib.js',
  library: 'MyLibrary',
  libraryTarget: 'umd'
}
```

Many packages publish multiple versions, for example one with ES modules for module bundlers like webpack or Rollup, and another one that works in Node (with `require`). A good example of doing this is Redux, which has a [simple build step](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/887bf072bbd5eb354f2e2bd2fbd3a4deb8ef1e90/package.json#L22-L26). It uses Babel to transpile the source and Rollup for the bundle, but the principle is the same for TypeScript and webpack.

Redux publishes three directories (see [unpkg - Redux](https://unpkg.com/redux@3.7.2/) for the full published structure):

```sh
dist/  # UMD bundles
es/    # ES modules version (same as lib/ but with ES modules)
lib/   # Transpiled version to work in Node
```

That means you could import `redux/dist/redux.js` if you want to use the UMD version, for example in a script tag, which is very simple thanks to unpkg (hopefully this is the primary use for globals).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux/dist/redux.js"></script>
```

Additionally, it defines [the `module` field](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/887bf072bbd5eb354f2e2bd2fbd3a4deb8ef1e90/package.json#L5-L7) which will be used by bundlers, that benefit from ES modules ([Rollup - `pkg.module`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module) for details), otherwise it will use `lib/index.js` (the `main` field). With webpack you can configure what fields you want to use with [`resolve.mainFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields). You might want to consider publishing such a structure, because having to import the whole bundle is not always necessary if you just want to use parts of it and ES modules enable [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) in Webpack, which the consumer of your library will appreciate because it will reduce the bundle size.

Comment: It's good to know `resolve.mainFields` exists and there is some support for multiple module patterns in a single package. However without this support extending to Typescript I will just get a compile error when I use the pattern that isn't in `index.ts` or `index.d.ts` in another Typescript file.

Comment: Nothing stops you from also publishing the TypeScript source, all you need to do to make it work, is using a TypeScript loader in webpack. But you can import JavaScript from TypeScript, that's not a problem. To have type definitions, you can publish them and refer to them with the `typings` field, many packages do that (even some that are not written in TypeScript, e.g. [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/887bf072bbd5eb354f2e2bd2fbd3a4deb8ef1e90/package.json#L8)).

Comment: The Typescript source would only describe the limited UMD (CommonJS and AMD only) and an auto generated `index.d.ts` would also reflect this. 

I can manually create a `d.ts` file that includes something like `export as namespace myModule` which would reflect what Webpack/Rollup had generated. But how would the Typescript compile know which to use if everything is in one package? I could use relative import statements (i.e. `import * as myModule from '../../../node_modules/my-module/globals/index'` but this has some obvious draw backs.

Comment: The typings describe the entire public API and it doesn't matter how the module is distributed.

Comment: So it would be acceptable to have a single `index.d.ts` including the namespace declaration even though in some situations (when you're using the UMD) that namespace wouldn't exist?